# Custom exception handling in WCF Service and Client

Tags: .net, exception, wcf, wcf-client

**What you think about this approach:**

*Fault helper:*

```
[Serializable]
public class WcfHwServiceFault
{
    private readonly Guid _guid;
    private readonly byte[] _data;

    private WcfHwServiceFault(Guid guid, byte[] data)
    {
        _guid = guid;
        _data = data;
    }

    public static WcfHwServiceFault Create(Exception ex)
    {
        var formatter = new SoapFormatter(null, new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.CrossMachine));
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        formatter.Serialize(ms, ex);

        return new WcfHwServiceFault(ex.GetType().GUID, ms.GetBuffer());
    }

    public Exception Get()
    {
        var formatter = new SoapFormatter(null, new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.CrossMachine));
        var ms = new MemoryStream(_data);
        return (Exception)formatter.Deserialize(ms);
    }
}
```

*Server side usage:*

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new FaultException<WcfHwServiceFault>(WcfHwServiceFault.Create(ex));
}
```

*Client side usage:*

```
try
{
    Channel.DoSomeMethod(...);
}
catch (FaultException<WcfHwServiceFault> ex)
{
    throw ex.Detail.Get();
}
catch (CommunicationException ex)
{
    throw new ApplicationException("Communication error.", ex);
}
```

Comment: What's the point of this? And why are you using `ApplicationException`? Don't you know you're not to use that anymore? Also, what's your reason for using runtime serialization? What if the exception isn't serializable? Did you have a real problem you were trying to solve?

Comment: 2 PostMan: This code is compilable and runnable:
catch (FaultException<WcfHwServiceFault> ex)
{
    throw ex.Detail.Get();
}
catch (CommunicationException ex)
{
    throw new ApplicationException("Communication error.", ex);
}

Comment: 2 John Saunders: 
1. Client uses business logic over common interfaces and set of appropriate exceptions (local).
2. Then we add proxy over wcf, but client as before use same interfaces and exceptions.
3. All exceptions of business logic will be serializable, but I think you ask very good questions. Thanks.

PS Sorry, if my english is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting idea. It saves you decorating your services with 100's of individual exceptions.

But why not just have exception as a property of WcfHwServiceFault?

Comment: This properties will be null on client side (after WCF deserializer), because they doesn't have appropriate attributes.